# How to get current from radio signal circuit

Tags: radio

I followed this circuit http://www.saers.com/recorder/craig/TENewsV2/TENews68/RadioWaveEnergy.jpg to harness radiowave and turn it into dc and it seems to generate around 1.4 volts but interestingly enough when i measure the amperage of the current there is zero amp...so i am looking on how to get the amp from the circuit kindly advise

Comment: You will only get microwatts (or less) from a radio antenna.

Comment: How did you measure the current? To measure any current you need a load connected to the circuit. Anyway, Peter is right, the power from such a circuit will be very low.

Comment: Something that may be useful to understand: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175121/rf-energy-harvesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you know the load (resistance) and the voltage across it, you can calculate the current with V=IR.

Assuming your multimeter has a 1 Megaohm input, that means you are getting 1.4 microamps (uA) -- This agrees with @PeterBennett estimate of microwatts. Power = V^2 / R = 1.4*1.4/1E6 = 1.96uW. Seems pretty good for a first try!

Depending on how precise your meter is, you could try a 1K load, we can estimate this would see 0.044V across it.

**Edit:** In addition to trying different known loads, see [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13047/how-to-measure-the-internal-resistance-of-a-voltmeter) for tips on determining the input resistance of your meter -- If it is a decent new one it might be higher than 1Mohm, in which case the power you're getting could be less than a mirowatt.